# Will snap packages get differential (delta) updates?

Tags: libreoffice, snap

I downloaded and installed LibreOffice 5.2.0 beta2 as described in [LibreOffice 5.2.0 beta2 as a snap package](https://skyfromme.wordpress.com/2016/06/14/libreoffice-5-2-0-beta2-as-a-snap-package/). It weighed in at 1015 MiB.

There will certainly be more updates before the RC is out. My question is this: will snap packages get differential (delta) updates or will the entire snap package, 1 GiB in this case, have to be downloaded each time?

(BTW: this version fixes the long-standing [vanishing clipboard content issue](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1240591#c1)!)

Postscript question: I want to know if I can delete `libreoffice_5.2.0.0.beta2_amd64.snap`, the 1 GiB "source" file, or must it remain on the system for the delta updates to work?

Comment: Yes you can delete the original snap. The squashfs images being mounted are stored in /var/lib/snapd/snaps-- don't delete those :) .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This [OMG! Ubuntu article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/04/ubuntu-16-04-lts-snap-packages) says delta:

> #### Newer Apps, Larger
>
> One side-effect of the ‘bundle’ approach is, naturally, a larger
>   initial package size.
>
> But Snaps are clever; transactional and delta updates allows devs to
>   only upgrade the parts that need updating, be it a single lib, an app
>   icon, or the entire freaking thing.

The [documentation on Snappy Ubuntu Core](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/) also mentions these points:

> - The OS and application files are kept completely separate, as a set of distinct read-only images.
> - Transactional, image-based delta updates for the system and applications that can always be rolled back.
> - These files are read-only, which means they cannot be tampered with and can be updated perfectly and predictably every time.
> - Signatures and fingerprints ensure you’re running exactly what was published by the developer, no funny business even if the bits came
>     from the internet.
> - Delta management keeps the size of downloads to the bare minimum.

Comment: I've added a bit to my question. Please see if you can throw some light on it. I want to know if I can delete `libreoffice_5.2.0.0.beta2_amd64.snap`, the 1 GiB "source" file or must it remain on the system for the delta updates to work?

Comment: @DKBose I can't find any information either way.

Comment: Please see Kyle's comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/787256/libreoffice-snap-package/787259?noredirect=1#comment1182039_787256

Answer (score 8):

We changed the format of snaps in 16.04, to a newer, more compact and more secure format. We have to add back delta updates in the new format, it will come soon. Also, we will add back auto-gardening so that old snap will be removed automatically in future, but you can safely delete it now yourself.

Answer (score 3):

And now it's here. Delta updates in new Snaps format
https://insights.ubuntu.com/2017/08/01/snap-updates-are-getting-smaller-heres-why/