# Sharing resources between snappy packages

Tags: ubuntu-core, snap

Sharing resources

My first example snap build is a java server I developed. I managed to create a snap that contains the jre, my server and the service startup. Everything works fine.

The snap file results in 106MB which is mainly java. I was wondering if there is a way to share the java installation between servers? So that my snap files become very small only containing specific code for my installation?

In my head this would sort of look like this:

Snap 1: A snap that contains the Java runtime and exposes java for others to use. I believe slots are used for that, but I am not 100% sure on that.
Snap 2: Server A that only contains my jars and uses the java runtime of Snap 1.
Snap 3: Like Snap 2 but with different jars.
I would have Snap 2 and 3 depend on Snap 1, so that if someone installs Snap 2, it would automatically install Snap 1. If Snap 1 is installed, it will skip that and simply use it?

I am not sure if this is supported or if this is even meant to work that way?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there will soon be a mechanism for you to share files in one of your snaps with other snaps that you made. Look out for the "content interface" in the next few weeks.

There will also be delta updates for snaps, which will reduce the upload / download for a given snap, but that's a separate matter.

Comment: Just a quick update, this [has landed in master](https://github.com/snapcore/snapd/pull/1360) and will make its way to you in a release very soon.

Answer (score 1):

From @didrocks answer:

This mecanism isn't available as of today (we may introduce one in the future, with the 3 separated snaps as you infer, but this isn't available now). Another option you can seek if, if snap 2 and 3 are tightly coupled, you can have one snap containing the jvm, and your 2 services. Then, some configuration to choose what to start (service 1, service 2 or the two of them).

Update:

I just saw: [Will snap packages get differential (delta) updates?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/787256/will-snap-packages-get-differential-delta-updates?rq=1) which essentially solves the issue I think. My worry was that I would have to repackage the JRE each time I publish a new version of my software. With delta update (which I yet have to work out how to do) this problem vanishes. I am happy for 1 package to have its own JRE whilst it is reusing it.

Edit again: As of now (20 June 2016) the delta updates are not released yet but are experimented on and will likely come soon. Source: #snappy on freenode

Comment: Part of the work is being discussed here: https://github.com/snapcore/snapd/pull/1360